# How can I make one character's dialogue in a play appear in a different font?

Tags: fonts, dramatist

I'm using the `dramatist` package and I would like certain characters to speak their dialogue in *italics* or smallcaps, to differentiate them. My current solution is to create a custom environment that wraps the `speaks` environment and puts it into *italics*, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following MWE provides an implementation where an extra macro `\characterfont` is added at the end of the `\xxxspeaks` macros. Using the `\Character{name}{abbreviation}` calls you can redefine `\characterfont` as part of the `name` argument. With a helper macro `\perfont` you can do a one time definition, i.e., define `\characterfont` as a font command followed by a self-redefinition to `\normalfont`. I leave the judgement whether this is elegant to the reader.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\def\characterfont{\normalfont} % initial setting
\makeatletter % copied from the dramatist.sty source code
\def\@character#1#2{%
    \@namedef{#2}{{\namefont #1}\xspace}
    \n@me@ppend@nddef{#2}{\@ppendname}{%
        \normalfont
        \if@drverse
            {\speakstab\speaksfont{#1}\speaksdel\par\nobreak\addvspace{-\parskip}}
        \else
            \item[#1\speaksdel]
        \fi\characterfont}% added extra command here
}
\makeatother

% use the font setting one time and switch to normalfont on next call
% needed to reset the value for characters that don't set the font explicitly
\def\perfont#1{%
\gdef\characterfont{#1\gdef\characterfont{\normalfont}}%
}

\begin{document}
% add font settings to character names
\Character{Alice\perfont{\itshape}}{ali}
\Character{Bob}{bob}
\Character{Charlie\perfont{\scshape}}{cha}

\begin{drama}
\alispeaks
Hi Bob!
\bobspeaks
Hi Alice! Have you seen Bob?
\chaspeaks
I'm not here.
\end{drama}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]